# Defining unit of measure in F# signature file

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

Is it possible to define a Unit of Measure in a signature file (.fsi)?

I have tried to add it after namespace definition,

```
[<Measure>] type unitOfMeasure
```

but the compiler complains "type unitOfMeasure is not defined". I need to re-define it in the implementation file (.fs).

Comment: Maybe this was overlooked but I think the reason might be that Units of Measure are not public visible (for the CLR) after all - they get erased after/while compilation

Comment: There is a typo in the question as well.

Comment: @CarstenKönig please add your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason might be that Units of Measure are not public visible (for the CLR) - they get erased after/while compilation